# custom scrollable tab bar on top iOS

Tags: ios, scrollbar, tabbar

I have a question about implementing a custom scrollable tab bar at the top of the screen in an iOS app. I am looking for a a tab bar very similar to the vevo app (pictured below). I have checked out this scrolling tab bar ( https://github.com/vermontlawyer/JFATabBarController ), but would like to move it to the top, and it seems to be glitchy when I edit the source code...I am assuming I can not use a standard tabbarcontroller for this but must make a custom tab bar....correct? How would I go about creating a custom scrolling tab bar at the top of the screen?

Thank you very much for any feedback!

[image: vevo tab screen 1]
[image: vevo tab screen 2]

Comment: You say that the control is "glitchy". What "glitches" are you seeing? I have used this control in a shipping app for ten months and have not received any complaints about "glitches".

Answer (score 7, accepted):

this project may help you: https://github.com/Marxon13/M13InfiniteTabBar but you need

Consist in a infinite UITabBar with a UIScrollView embedded in it ;) and it can be configure to put the tabbar in top of screen.

[image]

Hope it helps!

Comment: @AnkitGupta I can access. Could you try here? https://github.com/Marxon13?tab=repositories

Answer (score 1):

Basically, you'd do something like the following:

```
@class CustomTabBar;

@protocol CustomTabBarDatasource <NSObject>
- (int)numberOfElementsInCustomTabBar:(CustomTabBar *)bar;
- (NSString *)titleForTabAtIndex:(int)index inCustomTabBar:(CustomTabBar *)bar;
@end

@protocol CustomTabBarDelegate <NSObject>
- (void)customTabBar:(CustomTabBar *)bar activatedTabAtIndex:(int)index;
@end

@interface CustomTabBar : UIView
@property (weak) id<CustomTabBarDataSource> dataSource;
@property (weak) id<CustomTabBarDelegate> delegate;
@end

@interface YourViewController : UIViewController {
  CustomTabBar *myTabBar;
}
@end

@interface YourViewController (TabBarDataSource) <CustomTabBarDataSource>
@end

@interface YourViewController (TabBarDelegate) <CustomTabBarDelegate>
@end
```

The implementation for your `CustomTabBar` would include a `UIScrollView` and a set of `UIButton`s, whose title you would retrieve from the `dataSource`. When a button is fired, you'd call the `delegate`'s `customTabBar:activatedTabAtIndex:` method. Your `YourViewController` would change its content when the delegate method fires.

Answer (score 0):

You can have a look at this library: https://github.com/raihan/ZRScrollableTabBar. Which is simple and lightweight and may help you.

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for a similar solution, but ended up coming up with my own and wanted to share for anyone that might be looking at this later.

https://github.com/chrismanahan/Simple-Scrolling-Tab-Bar

It's a super simple way to create a sliding tab bar with the standard `UITabBarController` in your storyboard.