# How to make a menu like Hotstar application

Tags: ios, objective-c

How should I go about creating a menu like in Hotstar, where one can make a *half swipe* on the menu below the navigation bar? I suppose using a container rather than carousel view would be more suitable.

I am including a Hotstar app screenshot to illustrate my intent:

**NOTE:** 
I am not looking for frameworks implementing the drawer / side menu.

[image]

Comment: So... in other words "Stack, can you do the work and I will sit back and wait". You should at the very least show what you have tried, what you have researched or something more than "How do I do it, I haven't tried yet".

Comment: CATransition *transition = [CATransition animation];
    transition.duration = 0.3f;
    transition.timingFunction = [CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOut];
    transition.type = kCATransitionPush;
    if (swipeDirection==SwipeLeft) {
        transition.subtype=kCATransitionFromRight;
        
    }
    else{
        transition.subtype=kCATransitionFromLeft;
        
    }
    [smallNavController.view.layer addAnimation:transition forKey:nil];

Comment: So you want a slide bar? Put your code in the question, that will help better your chances of a successful answer.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26260677/custom-scrollable-tab-bar-on-top-ios and this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16810876/making-the-tab-bar-scrollable-in-iphone

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're looking for here, in fact, is a *sliding tab bar*. The philosophy of the UI element you describe is that it switches content (with or without animations - that's up to your preference/taste).

For start, I can point you to [M13InfiniteTabBar](https://github.com/Marxon13/M13InfiniteTabBar) or [ZRScrollableTabBar](https://github.com/raihan/ZRScrollableTabBar) but I'm sure there are many others (these are the ones I had the chance to try out). Both of them are implemented in Objective-C as you marked in the tags.

Of course they are not *exactly* what you showed in terms of design, but they aren't hard to customize.

Comment: Thanks for your help it did strike a bell

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking Like this side menu

https://github.com/mikefrederick/MFSideMenu