# How to change inactive tabbar 'more' item textcolor and image?

Tags: ios, swift, swift2, uitabbaritem

I have created a `UITabBarController` with seven of `TabBarItem` so all the icon image works fine by rendering as the original image.

Now the Question is how to change the *more* tabbar item text color and image in inactive state that is created automatically by the device?

I have tried with this but no luck :(

```
let tabBarAppearance = UITabBar.appearance()
tabBarAppearance.tintColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like as you can have maximum 5 tabs visible at the same time , you can either have a custom sliding tab bar e:g [custom scrollable tab bar on top iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26260677/custom-scrollable-tab-bar-on-top-ios) or You can have a view controller with table view with rest of controls on last tab and then you can control the color of last tab yourself e.g: [Change UITabbar tint colors from more menu in iOS8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26105507/change-uitabbar-tint-colors-from-more-menu-in-ios8)

Comment: I know this maximum tab bar is 5. Also, I want to confirm you that when the tab bar is more than five the iOS manages it automatically and make the more tab itself, so the question is how to change the more tab color of text and icon?

Comment: From my experience this cant be achieved as more is being managed by private API . If you find a way out please enlighten me as well as 1 year ago   when i tried it i couldn't achieve what you are trying to achieve today